# How do you get the index of a node in a left-right tree?

Tags: sql, modified-preorder-tree-t

I have left-right trees in my database which are a problem for performance. I'll switch to a system with a parentId and an orderId.

I'm looking for a sql script that can give me the index of a node in a left-right tree.

Comment: What is a left-right tree? Please post example input and expected output.

Comment: Man, see the tag, modified-preorder-tree-t and search google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
select COUNT(treestructureid) 
from TreeStructures s,
(select leftvalue, rightvalue, treeid, ParentTreeStructureId from TreeStructures where TreeStructures.TreeStructureId = 204260)
as data
where s.LeftValue <= data.LeftValue and s.RightValue <= data.RightValue
and s.TreeId = data.TreeId and s.ParentTreeStructureId = data.ParentTreeStructureId
```